# git branch/pull issues/questions

Tags: git, version-control

Here is my question related to branching

I have 3 branches in my repository testRepo

master, newbranch, and newbranch2

master has 1 file/in fact directory, newbranch has 5 and newbranch2 has 3 files in it. When I said, file, it could directory as well.

scenario 1.
I deleted everything in the local. Initialized a new local repo and I pulled from newbranch2. I got correct files and directory, but when I issued

a. git branch, I can see this
*master

b. when I tried to go to newbranch2 by typing git checkout newbranch2 it says

error: pathspec 'newbranch2' did not match any file(s) known to git.

c. But when I tried 'git checkout -b newbranch2, it worked/"

Switched to a new branch 'newbranch2'

Question: Is it by design ? do we have to create a branch locally before we can switch to to? but how it pulled the correct files and directory?

scenarios 2 Also, when I pull master then, or I pull master first and then newbranch2, it gives this error
remote: Counting objects: 16, done. remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done. remote: Total 16 (delta 4), reused 15 (delta 3), pack-reused 0 Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), done. From github.com:jeevnepali755/testRepo * branch master -> FETCH_HEAD Removing testOfRepo CONFLICT (modify/delete): README2.md deleted in 51cc62e79e35be66c5c93e9bc596ddfa7669e46b and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of README2.md left in tree. Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Regarding directories, no it couldn't.. Git does not store directories, only files.

Comment: Git can store/manage directory. This is not my question whether git can store directory or not.

Answer (score 0):

> scenario 1. I deleted everything in the local. Initialized a new local repo and I pulled from newbranch2. I got correct files and directory, but when I issued
>
> a. git branch, I can see this *master
>
> b. when I tried to go to newbranch2 by typing git checkout newbranch2 it says
>
> error: pathspec 'newbranch2' did not match any file(s) known to git.
>
> c. But when I tried 'git checkout -b newbranch2, it worked/"
>
> Switched to a new branch 'newbranch2'
>
> Question: Is it by design ? do we have to create a branch locally before we can switch to to? but how it pulled the correct files and directory?

As far as I can tell, yes, this is by design. Here are a few tips on working with branches.

Create a new branch starting from the latest commit from the local master branch.

```
git checkout -b newbranch2 master
```

Create a new branch starting from the latest commit from the *remote* master branch (usually GitHub)

```
git checkout -b newbranch2 origin/master
```

By the same token: continue working on a branch called "newbranch2", beginning from the latest commit on the remote repository.

```
git checkout -b newbranch2 origin/newbranch2
```

Branches can be confusing at first. The way I learned was to keep trying and experimenting, and to have others lead me through some strange situations. Also check out [this guide to branches](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

> scenarios 2 Also, when I pull master then, or I pull master first and then newbranch2, it gives this error remote: Counting objects: 16, done. remote: Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done. remote: Total 16 (delta 4), reused 15 (delta 3), pack-reused 0 Unpacking objects: 100% (16/16), done. From github.com:jeevnepali755/testRepo * branch master -> FETCH_HEAD Removing testOfRepo CONFLICT (modify/delete): README2.md deleted in 51cc62e79e35be66c5c93e9bc596ddfa7669e46b and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of README2.md left in tree. Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

What this means

- you deleted a file called README2.md on your local master branch
- there is a modification for README2.md on the remote master branch (origin/master) on GitHub

A possible way to fix

```
git status
# probably 'deleted by us: README2.md'
git add README2.md
#you can run 'git status' here if you wish
git commit -m "resolving conflict, taking README2.md from origin/master"
git status
# you will be ahead of origin/master
git push # make sure that remote has the latest changes
```

I hope that helps! Good luck.